Redirect from pipe back to console on windows with C program
I'm trying to create communication between a parent process and a child process
I'm using Windows and the C programming language.
The Parent Code:
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 61

void main()
{
    TCHAR ProcessName[256];// holds the child process path and the arguments to it
    STARTUPINFO si;// struct for startup information for the child process
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    char message[MSG_SIZE] = { 0 };
    DWORD written, bytesRead;
    char buffer[MSG_SIZE];
    HANDLE readHandle, writeHandle;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    
    printf("PIPE Father - Start");
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Please Enter a string - no more then 60 charcters: ");
    gets_s(message, MSG_SIZE-1);
    
    // Create pipe handles
    
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    
    if (!CreatePipe(&readHandle, &writeHandle, &saAttr, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("PIPE Father - Pipes are ready - Creating PIPE Child");
    
    // Set up the STARTUPINFO structure for the child process
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    si.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    si.hStdOutput = writeHandle;//allow child to write back
    si.hStdInput = readHandle;//allow child to read
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;// this is for notify to use the input,output         and error handles in the struct
    
    // Set up the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    
   // SetHandleInformation(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 1);

    wcscpy(ProcessName, L"C:\\q_2_son.exe");

    // Create the child process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, 
        ProcessName, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        TRUE, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        &si, 
        &pi)
        ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Sending message for child");
    
    
    if (!WriteFile(writeHandle, message, sizeof(message), &written, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }        
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Waiting for child");
    
    // Wait for the child process to exit
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
    // Read data from the pipe       
    if (!ReadFile(readHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Message Got back: >%s<", buffer);
    
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Closing Pipes");
    
    // Close the read end of the pipe
    CloseHandle(readHandle);
    
    // Close the write end of the pipe to the child process
    CloseHandle(writeHandle);
    
    //// Wait for the child process to exit
    //WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
    // Close process and thread handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    printf("\nPIPE Father - END");
}

The Child Code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 61
void invert_and_semi(char* message);
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    HANDLE readHandle, writeHandle;
    char message[MSG_SIZE] = { 0 };
    DWORD written, bytesRead;

    fprintf(stdout, "\nPIPE Child - Start");

    readHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    writeHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);


    // Read data from the pipe       
    if (!ReadFile(readHandle, message, MSG_SIZE, &bytesRead, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError reading from pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "\nPIPE Child - Original message: >%s<", message);

    invert_and_semi(message);

    fprintf(stdout, "\nPIPE Child - Updated message: >%s<", message);

    fprintf(stdout, "\nPIPE Child - Sending message to Father");

    if (!WriteFile(writeHandle, message, bytesRead, &written, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "\nPIPE Child - END");
    
}
void invert_and_semi(char* message)
{
    char *p = message;
    do
    {
        if (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z')
            *p -= 32;
        else if (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z')
            *p += 32;
        else
            *p = ';';
    } while (*++p);
}

When I run the parent code (which creates a process for the child and passes a string via a pipe)
only the parent code is printed to the console.
I've tried to redirect the stdout to the console with createFile, but I got an exception.
I tried to set si.hStdOutput to the console, but it didn't work either.
I tried many links in Stack Overflow, but nothing seemed to work for me.
The question is: how can I print the code with "fprintf(stdout, ..." to the console, and still return the result to the parent?
UPDATE
i rewrite the Father code and added 2 pipes
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MSG_SIZE 4096 


void main()
{
    TCHAR ProcessName[256] = L"C:\\q_2_son.exe";// holds the child process path and the arguments to it
    STARTUPINFO si;// struct for startup information for the child process
    HANDLE readChildInHandle = NULL, writeChildInHandle = NULL, readChildOutHandle = NULL, writeChildOutHandle = NULL;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    char message[MSG_SIZE] = { 0 };
    DWORD written, bytesRead;
    char buffer[MSG_SIZE];
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    
    printf("PIPE Father - Start");
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Please Enter a string - no more then 60 charcters: ");
    gets_s(message, MSG_SIZE-1);
    
    // Create pipe handles
    
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    
    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&readChildOutHandle, &writeChildOutHandle, &saAttr, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(readChildOutHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stdout SetHandleInformation\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&readChildInHandle, &writeChildInHandle, &saAttr, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 
    if (!SetHandleInformation(writeChildInHandle, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stdout SetHandleInformation\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    printf("PIPE Father - Pipes are ready - Creating PIPE Child");
    
    // Set up the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    // Set up the STARTUPINFO structure for the child process
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = writeChildOutHandle;
    si.hStdOutput = writeChildOutHandle;//allow child to write back
    si.hStdInput = readChildInHandle;//allow child to read
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;// this is for notify to use the input,output and error handles in the struct
    
   
    
   // SetHandleInformation(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 1);

    //wcscpy(ProcessName, L"C:\\q_2_son.exe");

    // Create the child process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, 
        ProcessName, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        TRUE, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        &si, 
        &pi)
        ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }   

    CloseHandle(writeChildOutHandle);
    CloseHandle(readChildInHandle);

    printf("\nPIPE Father - Sending message for child");
    
    
    if (!WriteFile(writeChildInHandle, message, sizeof(message), &written, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }        

    printf("\nPIPE Father - Waiting for child");
    
    // Wait for the child process to exit
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
    // Read data from the pipe       
    if (!ReadFile(readChildOutHandle, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from pipe\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Message Got back: >%s<", buffer);
    
    
    printf("\nPIPE Father - Closing Pipes");
    
    // Close the read end of the pipe
    CloseHandle(readChildOutHandle);
    
    // Close the write end of the pipe to the child process
    CloseHandle(writeChildInHandle);
    
    //// Wait for the child process to exit
    //WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
    // Close process and thread handles
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    printf("\nPIPE Father - END");
}

However, the problem remains (as you can see from the picture below no PIPE Child message exists).


I don't know if it's different in Windows, but pipes are usually one direction only. If you need to both write to and read from the child process, you need two pipes, one in each direction.

thank you for the replay, i have 2 pipes the father code sends and receives the data properly and it prints to the console what i send to prints. but the child does'nt print to screen i think i need to get the console handle then i'll be able to print, bu i don't know how.

You only call CreatePipe once. That creates one single pipe. You need two calls two create two pipes.

but how this will help me to print to console in the child code?

Use gender-neutral terms for processes on systems. Do not use gendered terms like father, grandfather, son, grandson, brother. Use gender-neutral terms like parent, grandparent, child, grandchild, sibling.

When you create the process, you say explicitly that the standard output (which would otherwise would be the console) is to be sent to the pipe. To print to the console only the standard error is possible. The problem I mentioned above is that you also say that standard input is the pipe. So everything the child process writes to standard output will be sent to the pipe, which will be read by the child process itself.

@Someprogrammerdude i've updated the code for 2 pipes and add an output image. the issue persists. however, in when i change the father code to be similar to the following link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output i'm getting the PIPE Child message but when i try to adjust my code like the link's code it didn't work (as you can see)
